# Why some of bootstrap glyphicon are not displayed correctly even i try in <i> and <span> tags including bootstrap file?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I use this tag than it displays envelope icon. 
But when I use tag:
 
It is not working.

Comment: Can you include your tag with the relevant classes applied so we can see what you've tried??

Comment: Could you please add your code ?.

Comment: Thanks,  here is my tag for envelope icon <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>

Comment: looks ok here -- http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_glyph_search&stacked=h -- all icons -- http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_comp_glyphs.asp

Comment: Please add a code snippet with your question so we can reproduce a solution based on it.

Comment: yeah Fazil,  I've written my code

Comment: Show that glyphicon icons which u used in your code.

Comment: Could you please have a look at my answer on [Bootstrap glyphicon not showing in Form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35659094/bootstrap-glyphicon-not-showing-in-form/35660280#35660280)?

Answer (score 0):

> Please add icon in after tag Like
>
> ## example:before {    content: "";    display: block;    width: 100px;    height: 100px; }